# Moving an HTML object seamlessly using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I try to move a DIV using jquery with the help of setTimeout, it just works fine and is moving seamlessly like this:

```
setTimeout("moveObject()", 10);

function moveObject() {
     $('.object').css("left", parseInt($('#object').css("left")) + 1);
}
```

It's moving like it's moving in Flash, you know seamlessly..
But there are some issues with setTimeout which has 10 ms, when the browser tab is in blur, timeout stops and doesn't make the job it has to.

Therefore, I thought it would be a good idea to use animate of JQuery to deal with this. I have changed the code to this:

```
$("#object").animate({left: parseInt($('#object').css("left")) + 100}, 1000, "linear", function() {} );
```

In the first code, object is moving 1px in 10ms. In the second code, object is moving 100px in 1000ms. So I think these two codes should do the same but they don't.

First code is moving object seamlessly, but the second is not that seamlessly. There are some corruptions in the movement.

My question is: How can I move this object (without using timeout) seamlessly? and It would be great if I can set a speed to that.
Note: I'm not using HTML5 so I'm looking for a solution which works with jquery & HTML

Comment: In jQuery-UI there are different [easings](https://jqueryui.com/easing/) included,perhaps this will help you.

Comment: Looks pretty smooth to me.

Comment: you can use velocity.js http://velocityjs.org/

Comment: Yes, I will check velocity.js, thank you Vijay

Comment: Huey, there are some differences in the movement when I make cross check on these two. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this question is this:requestAnimationFrame
https://gist.github.com/mrdoob/838785

Answer (score 2):

jQuery uses timeouts internally to animate, there's no other way to do this.
Generally you get better flow if you use the timers in [`Window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead of `window.setTimeout`, as it's built for animating and has higher precision..

What you really should be doing is looking at libraries like **[GSAP from Greensock](http://greensock.com/gsap)**, or consider using CSS3 for the animation, which would give you a much smoother animation most of the time.

Also note that you're really calling `eval` on the function as you're passing in a string to setTimeout that is evaluated, you should just reference the function

```
setTimeout(moveObject, 10);
```

and 10 milliseconds is a really low number, that used to be the absolute minimum, these days HTML5 sets it to 4ms, but not all browser follow that, only a few years back most browsers couldn't go below 50ms.

Comment: Animations with css3 is also looking good. They say: "you don't need to use Flash for animations"

Comment: Yes, CSS3 is usually very smooth, but can be a bit more complicated, and not everything is possible. GSAP is said to be as good, and in some cases better than CSS3, but I'm not quite sure about that. Both are better than jQuery, and probably a lot better than what you can do on your own without spending a lot of time on it.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by adeneo you should take a look at CSS3 animations. Here is a really good article on MDN about [transition property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition). Please also take a look at css transforms which should be useful in your case.

To smoothly move an element you only need to dynamically add below class to it.

```
.move-right {
  transform: translate3d(100px, 0px, 0px);
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

I've put together a small example which you might use as a starting point: https://jsfiddle.net/5bo5c8st/3/

Comment: Yes, it seems that CSS3 transform/transition is the solution. This is working great.